# Angular - Typescript dynamic import module using variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm building an Angular app that lazy loads modules without routing, simulating plugins.

I have this function in a Service that loads a module (hardcoded right now for simplicity), then renders the components returned in `mainBarComponents()` (a method in IPluginModule interface) in the `renderContainer` provided.

```js
loadViewFromPlugin(pluginPath: string, renderContainer: ViewContainerRef): any {
        import(pluginPath).then(({MiPrimerPluginModule}) => {
            // Compile the module
            this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(MiPrimerPluginModule).then((moduleFactory: { create: (arg0: Injector) => any; }) => {
                const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);
                const moduleInstance: IPluginModule = moduleRef.instance;
                const componentFactory = moduleInstance.mainBarComponents()[0];
                const {instance} = renderContainer.createComponent(componentFactory);
                // set component Input() property
                // instance.title = 'foo';

                // you have to manually call ngOnChanges for dynamically created components
                // @ts-ignore
                // instance.ngOnChanges();
            });
        });
    }
```

The code works if I set `pluginPath` as a literal string

```
import('./../../plugins/mi-primer-plugin/mi-primer-plugin.module').then(({MiPrimerPluginModule}) => {
```

But if I pass the parameter "pluginPath", then it throws at start:

```
./src/app/base/service/plugin-loader.service.ts:8:8-26 - Warning: Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

And when I want to initialize the module:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module './../../plugins/mi-primer-plugin/mi-primer-plugin.module'
Error: Cannot find module './../../plugins/mi-primer-plugin/mi-primer-plugin.module'
```

How can I fix this issue, so the pluginPath can be dynamic?

And how I could generify

```
import(pluginPath).then(({MiPrimerPluginModule}) => {
                             ^- this
```

Comment: I think `dynamic import` form requires `literal value`. This form also gets processed by many build tools.

Comment: That's a limitation of whatever loader you're using. Probably webpack. Other loaders, System.js. for example, can load arbitrary dynamic module specifiers